# Отловить элемент динамически изменяющийся img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Есть галерея, динамически меняет на главной странице 8 изображений. Есть задача обернуть каждое изображения в блок с текстом, который будет отображаться поверх изображения. Не получается отловить img
Вот пример кода html:

```
<ul id="vd">
    <li><img src="gallery/main_gallery/1.svg"/></li>
    <li><img src="gallery/main_gallery/2.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="gallery/main_gallery/3.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="gallery/main_gallery/5.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="gallery/main_gallery/6.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="gallery/main_gallery/7.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="gallery/main_gallery/8.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
<div id="p12">

</div>
```

Из блока с id=vd скрипт берет изображения для галереи отображает их в блоке с id=p12. Так вот не получается их вытащить из id=p12.
Вот код который формирует скрипт галереи в блоке id=p12:

```
 <div id="slideshowify-1480244926249" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; z-index: -2; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<img src="gallery/main_gallery/1.svg" style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; width: 1020px; height: 574.052px; top: 0px; transform: scale(1, 1); transition: transform 9000ms ease-in-out;">
   </div>
```

Вот сам скрипт:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.slideshowify = function(/* config */){

        var _self         = this,
            _imgs         = [],
            _imgIndex     = -1, 
            _imgIndexNext = 0,        // for preloading next            
            _transition   = true,     // use CSS3 transitions (default might be changed during init)
            _easing       = 'in-out',
            _viewEl       = document, // filled by slideshow (used for determining dimensions)
            _containerId  = "slideshowify-" + new Date().getTime(),
            _containerCSS = {
                "position" : "absolute",
                "overflow" : "hidden",
                "z-index"  : "-2",
                "left"     : "0",
                "top"      : "0",
                "width"    : "100%",
                "height"   : "100%"
            },
            _cfg = {
                parentEl      : "body",   // slideshow-container is injected into this
                blend         : "into",   // "into" || "toBg"
                randomize     : false,
                fadeInSpeed   : 1500,
                fadeOutSpeed  : 1500,
                aniSpeedMin   : 9000, 
                aniSpeedMax   : 15000
            },
            _$viewEl,
            _$parentEl;


        if (arguments[0]){
            $.extend(_cfg, arguments[0]); // reconfigure
            if (_cfg.parentEl != "body") {
                _viewEl = _cfg.parentEl;
            }
        }

        // local refs
        _$viewEl   = $(_viewEl);
        _$parentEl = $(_cfg.parentEl);


        /**
         * Fill viewEl with image (most likely cropped based on its dimensions and view size).
         * @TODO Add support for target divs whose dimensions were set with %s (get px value from parents).
         * @TODO Add a window resize handler (adjust photo dims/margins).
         */
        function _revealImg(curImg){
            var $img            = $(this),
                viewW           = _$viewEl.width(),
                viewH           = _$viewEl.height(),
                viewRatio       = viewW/viewH,
                imgRatio        = $img.width()/$img.height(),
                marginThreshold = Math.floor(Math.max(viewW, viewH)/10), // for zoom transitions
                direction       = Math.round(Math.random()),
                transAttr       = {},
                transProps,
                marginPixels,
                modDims; // will hold values to set and animate

            if (imgRatio > viewRatio){
                modDims = _transition ? 
                            direction ? {dim:'left', attr:'x', sign:'-'} : {dim:'right', attr:'x', sign:''} 
                            :
                            direction ? {dim:'left', attr:'left', sign:'-'} : {dim:'right', attr:'right', sign:'-'};
                $img.height(viewH + 'px').width(curImg.w * (viewH/curImg.h) + 'px');            
                marginPixels = $img.width() - viewW;
            }
            else {
                modDims = _transition ? 
                            direction ? {dim:'top', attr:'y', sign:'-'} : {dim:'bottom', attr:'y', sign:''} 
                            :
                            direction ? {dim:'top', attr:'top', sign:'-'} : {dim:'bottom', attr:'bottom', sign:'-'};
                $img.width(viewW+'px').height(curImg.h * (viewW/curImg.w) + 'px');
                marginPixels = $img.height() - viewH;
            }
            $img.css(modDims.dim, '0');
            transAttr[modDims.attr] = modDims.sign + marginPixels + 'px'; 

            // if marginThreshold is small, zoom a little instead of panning
            if (_transition && marginPixels < marginThreshold){
                if (direction){ // zoom out 
                    $img.css('scale','1.2');
                    transAttr = {'scale':'1'};
                }
                else { // zoom in
                    transAttr = {'scale':'1.2'};
                }
            }

            transProps = {
                duration : Math.min(Math.max(marginPixels * 10, _cfg.aniSpeedMin), _cfg.aniSpeedMax),
                easing   : _easing,
                queue    : false, 
                complete : function(){
                    _$parentEl.trigger('beforeFadeOut', _imgs[_imgIndex])
                    $img.fadeOut(_cfg.fadeOutSpeed, function(){
                        _$parentEl.trigger('afterFadeOut', _imgs[_imgIndex]);
                        $img.remove();
                    });
                    _loadImg();

                }
            };

            _$parentEl.trigger('beforeFadeIn', _imgs[_imgIndex]);
            $img.fadeIn(_cfg.fadeInSpeed, function(){
                    $img.css('z-index', -1);
                    _$parentEl.trigger('afterFadeIn', _imgs[_imgIndex])
                });

            // use animate if css3 transitions aren't supported
            _transition ? 
                $img.transition($.extend(transAttr, transProps)) :
                $img.animate(transAttr, transProps);
        }   // end of _revealImg()


        /**
         * Loads image and starts display flow
         */
        function _loadImg(){
            var img     = new Image(),
                nextImg = new Image(), // for preloading
                len     = _imgs.length;

            _imgIndex = (_imgIndex < len-1) ? _imgIndex+1 : 0;

            $(img)
                // assign handlers
                .load(function(){
                    if (_cfg.blend==='into'){
                        $(this).css({'position':'absolute', 'z-index':'-2'});
                        $('#'+_containerId).append(this);
                    }
                    else { // @TODO verify that this works
                        $('#'+_containerId).empty().append(this);
                    }
                    _revealImg.call(this, _imgs[_imgIndex]);
                })
                .error(function(){
                    throw new Error("Ой не могу загрузить изображение.");
                })
                .hide()
                .attr("src", _imgs[_imgIndex].src); // load

            if (_imgIndexNext == len) return; // nothing left to preload

            // preload next image
            _imgIndexNext = _imgIndex + 1;
            if (_imgIndexNext < len-1){
                nextImg.src = _imgs[_imgIndexNext].src;
            }
        } // end of _loadImg()


        // INITIALIZE
        if (!$.support.transition) {
            _transition = false;
            _easing = 'swing';
        }


        if (!_cfg.imgs){ // images were passed as selector 
            // load images into private array
            $(this).each(function(i, img){
                $(img).hide();
                _imgs.push({
                    src : $(img).attr('src'),
                    w   : $(img).width(),
                    h   : $(img).height()
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            _imgs = _cfg.imgs;
        }


        if (_cfg.randomize){ 
            _imgs.sort(function(){ return 0.5 - Math.random(); });
        }


        // create container div 
        $("<div id='"+_containerId+"'></div>")
            .css(_containerCSS)
            .appendTo(_cfg.parentEl);


        // start
        _loadImg();

        return this;
    };

    /**
     * Expose slideshowify() to jQuery for use without DOM selector.
     */ 
    $.slideshowify = function(cfg){
        var _self = this,
            _cfg  = {
                dataUrl  : "",
                dataType : "json",
                async    : true,
                filterFn : function(data){ return data; } // default filter. does nothing
            };

        $.extend(_cfg, cfg);

        $.ajax({
            url      : _cfg.dataUrl,
            dataType : _cfg.dataType,
            async    : _cfg.async,
            success  : function(imgs){
                _cfg.imgs = _cfg.filterFn(imgs);            
                $({}).slideshowify(_cfg);
            }
        });
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: так а сам скрипт где?

Comment: скрипт добавил выше

Comment: Откуда берется текст?

Comment: текст не играет роли, главное не получается отследить изменение изображений